# Who changed Deployment tags

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

With Azure DevOps 2019 you now have to click Save when changes are made to Deployment Tags.  Is there a way to find out who made the changes? I can't find it in any screen or report and I've not fond anything in the database. I'm hoping that the who is saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Tags for the Targets in the Deployment group. It seems that the log of the changes made to the tags are indeed not recorded.

You can [report this problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=22) to Microsoft development team. Hope they will look into this problem and fix it in the future sprint.